# Memory game - texture on cards

Tags: unity, textures, blender, materials

I'm new with Unity and I'm working on recreating memory game. I found this sample: http://xtasestudios.com/unity/samples (select "Memory"). I decided for C#.

I've created my own card in Blender, added 3 different materials (without textures), also I created flip-flop animations. After importing .blend file in Unity and assigning scripts, textures, animations, positioning camera etc..

Everything works fine, except textures on cards. 
I can change color on cards, but when I want to see any texture on my card, I see only color, not whole texture. I really have no idea why is this happening and how to fix it.

Any help will be appreciated! [image]

Comment: You said you created the cards in Blender (I'm not sure why; they're just squares) but did you assign texture coordinates? Texture images won't appear on a model without texture coordinates.

Comment: I've assigned materias as it is in this tutorial: [link](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Multiple_Materials) For assigning texture coordinares I have to learn UV mapping first, right? I'll need some time for that... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see a texture properly on a card, you need to first UV unwrap the mesh in blender.

- Press Tab to get into edit mode on your card object.
- Press A until you have all of your vertices selected
- Press U and do a Smart UV Unwrap
- Bring up a UV/Image editor window.
- Make a new UV image or open your card image.
- Fidget with the UVs until you get it lined up like you want.
- Re-export your object into Unity. It will now have predictable texture results.

I personally like to use the UV window to export my UV layout to an image file that I can open in photoshop and use as a guide for making my textures. Then you could re-use a single card mesh with a single UV layout and just re-assign multiple textures for different cards, knowing they will all line up.

Comment: Many thanks for the help! You were right, I needed to do UV mapping. Somehow I didn't find it in the .fbx file from sample.